# es6 Map() doesn't compile to es5 when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6

I've just started using Typescript in a project for the first time.

I really want to use Map() to organize a small array of key value pairs.

Unfortunately when the typescript is compiled (using gulp and gulp-typescript) to vanilla, ES5 JavaScript, Map() still exists. I need this code to work in ie9.

Any advice at this stage would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't convert ES6-only types to earlier versions of JavaScript; it converts typed JavaScript to vanilla JavaScript. So your question doesn't really have much to do with TypeScript.

Comment: Use a polyfil. It won't be 100% but you should be able to work with it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I understand now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Map` is a part of ES6 and have nothing to do with TypeScript.

If you want tot use `Map` in ES5 environment you should include an appropriate polyfill.

My first two thoughts are:

- [`es6-map` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map)
- `core-js/es6/map` from [`core-js` generic ES6 polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try the es6-map module. Thanks again

Comment: The fact that Map is a part of ES6 and not TypeScript, while true, is a bit misleading in this context. TypeScript does compile other ES6+ features to ES5 (such as classes, arrow functions and async functions).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a shim or a polyfill.

I've used [es6-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map) once and it's pretty good.

Unfortunately there is no TypeScript definitions for it, so my suggestion would be using [es6-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es6-shim/) directly from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/es6-shim) and add this to your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    }
}
```

You'll be able to use ES6 Map strongly typed, your code will be compiled down to ES5 and old browsers would support it through the shim.