# this.map.set(key,value) function is not working in angualr 6 typescript 2.9.2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, typescript2.0

I have a map(`this.mymap`) of type `Map<string, Person[]>` where `Person`is a class and addEntry() function. But it is giving me an error below when I try to set the entry in `this.mymap` variable.

> this.mymap.set is not function

**component.ts**

```js
    addEntry(value:Person[]){
    Object.keys(this.mymap).forEach(key => {
                this.mymap.set(key,value);
              });
    }
```

**package.json**

```js
    {
      "name": "demo-ui",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "6.1.10",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/material": "6.4.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.1.2",
        "@types/core-js": "^2.5.2",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
        "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
        "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.2.0",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
        "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "file-saver": "1.3.8",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.5",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "3.0.1",
        "ngx-spinner": "^7.1.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "xlsx": "0.12.13",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
        "@angular/language-service": "6.1.10",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
        "@types/node": "8.9.4",
        "jasmine-core": "2.9.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "protractor": "5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "4.1.0",
        "tslint": "5.9.1",
        "typescript": "2.9.2"
      }
    }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
      }
    }
```

I need to add an entry in map using map.set function.

Comment: You should use `Map.keys` directly instead of `Object.keys`

Comment: How sure are you that `this.mymap` is a `Map` instance?  The relevant code isn't present, so this doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  Consider making an example which demonstrates your issue in a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//).

Comment: HI, @uminder  Thanks. But Map.keys() is also not working, basically all typescript Map and Set functions are not working in my angular 6 project, I am using typescript 2.9.2 version.

Comment: @Shweta Have you properly initialized this.mymap as Map?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya  yes. `mymap = new  Map<string, Person[]>()`

Comment: Try to use `Array.from` like this `Array.from(this.mymap.keys()).forEach(...)` because `Object.keys(this.mymap)` will return empty `[]` list.

Comment: @hrdkisback yeah thanks, I have used these functionality these are working in my code ... but my main problem is with `set(key,value)` function of map.

Comment: Still, you got the issue in `set(key, value)` method by using `Array.from`?

Comment: yes @hrdkisback

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427777/es6-map-doesnt-compile-to-es5-when-using-typescript you are compiling your typescript under `es5` target. try to add `"es6"` in `tsconfig.json` file under `"lib"` property.

Comment: @hrdkisback    Updated tsconfig.json file is:
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "core-js"
    ]
  }`
but still no map function are working in my project.

Comment: Try to add ES6 polyfill library in project.  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/es6-shim or https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map